# How to pass a variable within a regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have the ff regex:

```
var str = 'hi there I am';

function testing(input, int){

  var par = input.match(`/.{1, ${int}}/g`);
  console.log(par);
}

console.log(testing(str, 5));
```

How can I passed in the argument/variable `n`to make it work on the regex?

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
function maxTotal(n){
  console.log(`/.{1,${n}}/g`);
  //var max = total.match(`/.{1,${n}}/g`);
}

maxTotal(4);
```

Comment: It seems doesnt work on my end. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What browser do you use? You can see the links, which are duplicated to your question

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Look at this here: https://jsbin.com/cabovugoyo/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Your ES version of the bin is under 6, so this is the problem. For other cases see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: can you tell me how